# SourceTree File Corruption on OSX

Tags: mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

For some reason, Irrespective of what changes I make, the 1st line in a particular file (EmailService.groovy) is the only change that is displayed by SourceTree when committing.

I have tried marking the file as untracked, then re-tracking but this doesn't seem to have any effect at all.

In the following example code, if I were to change "return true" to "return false", source tree will still only report that the 1st line (the package) has changed. Upon comitting, bitbucket(we use Mercurial) also only reports changes on the 1st line, however when pulled on another machine, the file is there including all its changes.

How can I fix this file such that the changes to the file are tracked correctly?

I have looked for an answer on this one, but i cannot seem to find others with the same issue.

Note: This only happens to one file in the repository, all others work just fine

Example

```
package my.package // SourceTree/Mercurial reports all changes on this line only

class EmailService {

  public Boolean someMethod(String someArg) {
    return true // Even when this is the line I changed
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you maybe upload the file somewhere and put a download link in your question ?

Comment: I'm sorry this file is sensitive and cannot be shared publicly without heavy editing which I believe would defeat the purpose

Answer (score 0):

I think I run into similar problem. In my case source tree is showing following:

[image]

And every time I change something in this specific file it only shows these changes and nothing else. In my case it is also happening to this one special file and nothing else. Hence I can live with it somehow, but it stays annoying...